# Embedding a live chat conversation as view only on an HTML page

Tags: chat, embed, slack-api, hipchat

I am looking to add a live chat channel as a view only on a static HTML page and can't seem to find a viable solution.

As opposed to a realtime chat popup for support, I am looking to create a view only window into a live chat, using something like Slack, HipChat, Telegram, etc.

The end goal is to create almost a liveblog, consisting of multiple authenticated users who are actively chatting while site visitors are only able to view the chat.

Any ideas would be appreciated but preferably the chat client would be cross platform for web, desktop, mobile use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slack would work for this kind of scenario. Slack gives you three tools for "streaming" life chat out of Slack:

- [Outgoing webhooks](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks)
- [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm)
- [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api).

Webhooks are very easy to use, but have some severe limitations. The RTM API is the most powerful, but more challenging to implement because it uses websockets and the Even API is good middle ground, which I would recommend for most cases.

I am not aware of any existing solution for your problem, but if you want to go this way my suggestion would be to look for an existing chat solution for your websites, that you can couple with Slack. Slack sends a HTTPS POST request for each chat message, which could probably be translated to an input for an existing chat solution.